# Error log in PHP Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently using Codeigniter as my default framework to create some my projects. But, when I uploaded the projects on my servers and after 3 three days the error log has achieved over 1 mb in my server. How can I ignore this error log? Does the error log caused by my server or codeigniter itself ?

Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste a part of the error log. There might be many reasons for the logs:
-If you are using PHP 5.3 there will be a ton of 'depracated' errors
-Favicon missing
-An application error, which you would need to fix.
All the answers are in the log file, go through it.

Comment: @Jamie : Both (Apache and CI)

How can I disable the error log. Here is the the error log looks like:
[15-Aug-2011 21:40:21] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

[19-Aug-2011 06:16:13] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/cimeric1/public_html/grandsakurahotel.com/new/framework/application/views/uiwebview/bookpackage_view.php on line 62

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is the **Codeigniter** error logging you are referring to, check your `config.php` for the `log_threshold` setting and set it to `0` to disable error logging:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

I usually set it to `1`, at least while in development. If you do enable error logging, you should *read* the error logs and correct the errors if possible, otherwise it is pointless.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That was really help. I'll try. But does it ignore the error from my server (Apache). The error something like this:

[15-Aug-2011 21:40:21] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0